# Finding a Custom Object Id (01I...) to get the Setup page URL

Tags: apex, sobject, id

I'm trying to find a way to get the "Id" for a custom object's setup page. So I'm NOT trying get a record Id. I'm working on a custom visualforce page and I'm setting up a link so that when the user clicks it, it'll direct them to the object's setup page. I've included a picture  below to show what I'm am trying to get.

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone know of a way to query for that Id through Apex? I tried using the describe methods, but had no luck...

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!

- Ryan

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Update

We can now query those `01I` object ids and `00N` field ids directly without Tooling API or callouts.

```
List<EntityParticle> entities = [
    SELECT DurableId
    FROM EntityParticle
    WHERE EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'MyCustom__c'
];
```

This will return:

```
DurableId
01I7F000001fbTC.LastViewedDate
01I7F000001fbTC.LastReferencedDate
01I7F000001fbTC.00N7F00000HnXIU
01I7F000001fbTC.00N7F00000HnXIW
...
```

Much easier than the historical solution - and no Session ID involved or API privilege issues.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. 

I have another question. I had to set a remote site (the site I used was the one given to me by Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl() ) manually. Do you know a way to set a remote site dynamically or a way to find an even more generic web address that I could set as the remote site? I'm looking for something that'll work across different instances and not require the user to manually set the remote site for every different instance.

Comment: @user7702 Maybe in lieu of a callout you can get creative with `PageReference.getContent()` and a relative URL which doesn't require a Remote Site Setting.

Comment: Great answer, but the syntax is out of date, Always refer to the latest SF official document on this for syntax: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_resource_examples.htm